# webkitTransform with jQuery

Tags: jquery, webkit, transform

When I use this code, everything works fine:

```
document.getElementById('cube').style.webkitTransform = "rotateX("+xAngle+"deg) rotateY("+yAngle+"deg)";
```

But, when I use this `jQuery` code, it won't work:

```
jQuery('cube').css('-webkit-transform', "rotateX("+xAngle+"deg) rotateY("+yAngle+"deg)");
```

Where is the difference?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it should be:

```
jQuery('#cube').css('webkitTransform', "rotateX("+xAngle+"deg) rotateY("+yAngle+"deg)" );
```

or

```
jQuery('#cube').css('webkit-transform', "rotateX("+xAngle+"deg) rotateY("+yAngle+"deg)" );
```

Comment: @Neal they're both the same. jQuery converts the second one to the first one. Look at the method `jQuery.camelCase`

Answer (score 1):

Your forgot a `#`:

```
jQuery('#cube').css('-webkit-transform', 
                         "rotateX("+xAngle+"deg) rotateY("+yAngle+"deg)" );
```

See fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/fxxHa/

Comment: it should be `webkitTransform` or `webkit-transform`. jQuery will convert this to `WebkitTransform`. `jQuery.camelCase( "-webkit-transform") ===
"WebkitTransform"`

Comment: Looks like chrome defines both. So I remove my downvote. `document.createElement("div").style.webkitTransform ===
""
document.createElement("div").style.WebkitTransform ===
""
document.createElement("div").style.WebKitTransform ===
undefined`

Comment: Yeah, you got lucky there. :P